# Reference expression in switch

Tags: php, switch-statement

In PHP, is it possible to get a reference to the expression used in the switch statement?

For example:

```
switch ($_POST['id']) {
    case 0:
        $id = <switch expression>
        break;
    case 1:
        $id = <switch expression>
        break;
    default
        $id = null;
}
```

so if `$_POST['id'] = 1`, then `$id = 1`

Then I can test for `if (! $id) {}`

Obviously you are probably thinking why not just use `$id = $_POST['id']` but in the real example it looks like this

```
switch (strtolower($load->post('payment_method')))
{
    case 'paypal':
        $payment_method = <switch/case expression>;
        $payment_type = 'ewallet';
        break;
    case 'bitcoin':
        $payment_method = <switch/case expression>;
        $payment_type = 'ecurrency';
        break;
    default:
        //$payment_method = null; // taken from card number
        $payment_type = 'card';
}
```

I dont want `$payment_method` assigned.

**HAD A EUREKA MOMENT WHILST WRITING THIS**
Well, that works for what I was trying to achieve anyway.

```
switch (($payment_method = strtolower($load->post('payment_method'))))
{
    case 'paypal':
        $payment_type = 'ewallet';
        break;
    case 'bitcoin':
        $payment_type = 'ecurrency';
        break;
    default:
        unset($payment_method); // taken from card number
        $payment_type = 'card';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no way

use for example such way

```
$cases = array(0, 1, 3 ,5);
$defaultVal = 1;
$id = in_array($_POST['id'], $cases) ? $_POST['id']: $defaultVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such feature in PHP.

But you can do what you are looking for as easy as this:

```
switch (strtolower($load->post('payment_method')))
{
    case 'paypal':
        $payment_method = 'paypal';
        $payment_type = 'ewallet';
        break;
    case 'bitcoin':
        $payment_method = 'bitcoin';
        $payment_type = 'ecurrency';
        break;
    default:
        $payment_method = null; // taken from card type
        $payment_type = 'card';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just realize that this probably *is* possible using a simple workaround:

```
switch ($switch_value = strtolower($load->post('payment_method')))
{
    case 'paypal':
        $payment_method = $switch_value;
        $payment_type = 'ewallet';
        break;
    case 'bitcoin':
        $payment_method = $switch_value;
        $payment_type = 'ecurrency';
        break;
    default:
        $payment_method = null; // taken from card type
        $payment_type = 'card';
}
```

;-)

Comment: i think just `unset($payment_method)` would be better in this case :)

Comment: @Christian That is certainly another aproach, yes. But this answers the OPs question closer.